# MariaDB Pivot Table Performace

Tags: sql, mariadb, pivot-table, query-performance

I have a table containing data with dynamic categories:

```
+----------+--------------+---------------+---------+
| category | string_value | integer_value | user_id |
+----------+--------------+---------------+---------+
| cat_1    | NULL         | 1             |       1 |
| cat_1    | NULL         | 3             |       2 |
| cat_2    | foo          | NULL          |       1 |
| cat_2    | bar          | NULL          |       2 |
+----------+--------------+---------------+---------+
```

I need a pivoted version of this table which I use with statement:

```sql
select
  user_id,
  max(case when category == 'cat_1' then integer_value end) as 'cat_1',
  max(case when category == 'cat_2' then string_value end) as 'cat_2',
from my_table
group by user_id
```

This creates results in the following format:

```
+---------+-------+-------+
| user_id | cat_1 | cat_2 |
+---------+-------+-------+
|       1 |     1 | foo   |
|       2 |     3 | bar   |
+---------+-------+-------+
```

This query by itself is performing well also for many categories and table entries (e.g., for 8 categories and 240k entries, it takes around 20ms), but if i wrap this exact query in a `select * from <query>`, performance drops significantly (to 650ms).

Also, ordering by `user_id` does not influence the performance significantly, whereas ordering by any other field also causes a performance drop, even if an index of the respective field and `user_id` exists. I'm guessing that this approach in itself is not feasible for larger tables?
However, I am curious what causes the extra execution time when adding the `select * from <query` part.

Background: I try to use this query to store dynamic user data, and I'd like to prevent changes to the table structure at runtime (i.e., adding a column). Any alternative would be welcome. I'm using MariaDB 10.5.5, and I need the solution to also work with MySQL 5.7 and SQL Server 2019.

#### Execution Plans:

Without surrounding `select * from`:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+-----+--------+---------+----------+------------+-------+    
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref | rows   | r_rows  | filtered | r_filtered | Extra |
|----|-------------|-----------|-------|---------------|------------|---------|-----|--------|---------|----------|------------|-------|
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user_data | index |               | user_index |         |   9 | 226067 | 1619.00 |    100.0 |      99.88 |       |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+-----+--------+---------+----------+------------+-------+
```

With surrounding `select * from`:

```
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+-----+--------+-----------+----------+------------+-------+ 
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref | rows   | r_rows    | filtered | r_filtered | Extra |
|----|-------------|------------|-------|---------------|------------|---------|-----|--------|-----------|----------|------------|-------|
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL   |               |            |         |     | 226067 |    200.00 |    100.0 |      100.0 |       |
|  2 | DERIVED     | user_data  | index |               | user_index |       9 |     | 226067 | 242418.00 |    100.0 |      100.0 |       |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+-----+--------+-----------+----------+------------+-------+
```

Comment: please share original execution plan and the execution plans for the modified ones.

Comment: A flexibel data model is a perfect use case for JSON, all thre DBMSes should support it. Add new columns to the JSON and create a view on top of it extracting those columns.

Comment: Please add `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Are there 121K rows in the resultset?  What client is doing the timing?

Comment: For MariaDB, see See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56670844/1766831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my speculation on what is happening.

You have an index on the underlying table which MariaDB uses for the aggregation.  That means that no sorting is done . . . and just by reading the index, it can start returning rows.

This is a very nice feature.  But when you just run the query, you are seeing the time to *first* row.

When you use a derived table, MariaDB must generate *all* the rows before returning *any* of them.  So, the `select *` with a subquery is doing much more work.

That is why the second version is slower than the first.  I would expect a query that returns many tens of thousands of rows to take more than 20 milliseconds on most machines.

Comment: I foolishly did not realize that my tooling was adding a LIMIT that I was not aware of. You are very right. Thank you!